# SQL generate all possible combination between group items on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, combinations

I have a SQL table and I would like to generate all combinations between groups.

**Combination will not be included itself**

**My Code:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_Group_Item') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_Group_Item
GO

SELECT  *
INTO    #tmp_Group_Item
FROM    (
VALUES
     (1, 1)
    ,(1, 2)
    ,(1, 3)
    ,(2, 1)
    ,(2, 2)
    ,(3, 1)
    ,(3, 2)
    ,(3, 3)
) AS t(GroupID, ID)
```

**Expected Result would be like below**

```
CombinationID   GroupID ID
-------------   ------- --
1               1       1
1               2       1
1               3       1
2               1       1
2               2       1
2               3       2
3               1       1
3               2       1
3               3       3

4               1       2
4               2       1
4               3       1
5               1       2
5               2       1
5               3       2
6               1       2
6               2       1
6               3       3

7               1       3
7               2       1
7               3       1
8               1       3
8               2       1
8               3       2
9               1       3
9               2       1
9               3       3
...
```

I have tried with cross and full outer join but not able to do it.

Comment: What is your input ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'all combinations between groups'?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried with cross join itself 
SELECT *  
FROM #tmp_Group_Item c1
   CROSS JOIN #tmp_Group_Item c2

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with a cross apply, e.g.:

```sql
select [CombinationID] = identity(int, 1, 1), GroupID, ID
into #tmp_Group_Item
from (values (1), (2), (3)) a(GroupID)
cross apply (values (1), (2), (3)) b(ID);

select * from #tmp_Group_Item;
```

which yields:

```
CombinationID   GroupID ID
            1         1  1
            2         1  2
            3         1  3
            4         2  1
            5         2  2
            6         2  3
            7         3  1
            8         3  2
            9         3  3
```